# Android: How to create a Detail alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've been playing around with alert dialogs. I want to show a dialog that shows particular information about a list item in listview. Just like the android's file manager's detail dialog.

Picture: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20856352/detailsbox.jpg

Interesting thing about this Details dialog is that it shows list items which are very similar to Preference item in a Preferences Screen. They can be clicked upon, they're showing a very nicely laid out two-line item listitem.

I need to create a similar dialog box but I've no clue how to accomplish this. I've played around a bit. Preference XML cannot be used as alertdialog's layout. And I'm unable to develop a layout that looks similar to the above pic. Need help / guideline how to achieve this.

Faraz Azhar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to use a custom dialog because it will be difficult to replicate the look of the AlertDialog.  An AlertDialog can display a list of items using AlertDialog.setListAdapter.  You can customize the list of items to show two rows of text per item by using a custom implementation of ListAdapter.  The attached screenshot was produced by the below code and xml.

[image]

```
public class Temp extends Activity
{
    private String[] listItemsFirstRow = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
    private String[] listItemsSecondRow = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(), null);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return listItemsFirstRow.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            //this isn't great
            return listItemsFirstRow[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText( listItemsFirstRow[position]);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText( listItemsSecondRow[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:minHeight=![enter image description here][2]"?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems the be the exact thing which I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just made your xml file same as regular screen/page

then put this code on your onCreate()

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_info,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(layout);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
```

which r.layout.toast_info is your xml file
and r.id.toast_layout_root is your root xml id (eg. '<'linearlayout android:id="+@id...."'>' )

and when you want to show it just write this line

> alertDialog.show();

Comment: Thanks for a super prompt reply. But what you've explained is what I already know. I know how to inflate an alertdialog and show it. My issue is that notice the two-line listitem in the image. I need guideline how to create that layout. I already know how to plug that layout into the alertdialog and show it. Thanks again.

Comment: @FarazAzhar You can design your list item, then inflate a list view (for example) to the dialog. You can also handle click events…

Comment: Hi Faraz,
I might not understand your question properly.
So, your question is how to make a nice layout as same as your attached file? do you mean about that listview ?

Comment: If it yes, you might get some hint by seeing this tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: Yes my question is about designing the dialog's layout as close to the attached image as possible.

Comment: @ToonSuperLove Are you suggesting that this is an ordinary listview with two-lined listitem in a simple custom dialog?

Comment: @FarazAzhar Yes, I didnt notice anything different than an ordinary dialog. If it has, please explain so I might mislook it

Comment: @ToonSuperLove Well I was able to create the dialog as per my linked image, thanks to info provided by [ab11]. However Im still unable to set color schemes on it like the ones used in linked image. I try setting ?android:attr/textColorPrimary and it crashes my app. How do i set the "predefined theme color" from android resources that make the list item's first line as blue color in small text, and second line as black color in large text. I can manually set colors using hex and rgb values. But i wanted to stick to android's built-in resources / styles / themes.

Comment: @FarazAzhar The easiest way is you already specific it in an xml component like
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 

however, in case you need to set in code, you could set it in Adapter same as "setText" command as Ab11 wrote:
ex. ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText( listItemsSecondRow[position]);
so you just need to write
((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA"));

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an Activity as a dialog.  This way it is pretty easy to create a custom dialog.  Here is a small example which I think you can build upon.

```
**Activity**

public class CustomDialogEx extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {  // pass your string data via this intent to the custom view
    // show the custom dialog
    Intent i = new Intent();
    // i.putExtra(<your key/value pairs here>
    i.setClass(this, DialogActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);   
}
}

****************************************************************************

**Custom Dialog**

// The Activity will serve as the Dialog

public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    b.getString(<your key>)
}
}

*****************************************************************************

**AndroidManifest**

<activity
    android:name="DialogActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this may also help you

public class ShareDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Context  mcontContext;
    Button  btnok;
    Listview lstview;

    public ShareDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);     
        mcontContext= context;
                //pls replace with your dialog.xml file
        setContentView(R.layout.sharedialog);       
        bindComponent();
        addListener();      
    }
    private void bindComponent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lstview=(Listview) findViewById(R.id.lstdetail);
        btnok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);

             //bind here listview with your adpter
    }

    private void addListener()
    {

        btnshareviwifi.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnok:


                  dismiss();     

            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}


and where you want to show

ShareDialog  shobje=new ShareDialog  (context);

shobje.show()
```